# How can I add an undefined number of digit characters to a string, so then I can convert the string to an int?

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm, sorting

I wanted to write a simple program that asks you to enter numbers by keyboard (being each number separated by a space or by a comma) and then sorts them from lower to higher.

What I had in mind was asking the user to enter the numbers by keyboard, setting the input to a String object, and then passing the String through a for loop that determines if a character is a digit or a normal character.
If the caracter is a digit, it would be appended to a String array's field and look for the next digit and do the same thing until one character isn't a digit; in which case, it would look for another digit and repeat the same process but with the next String array's field.
Once the program has passed through the hole String's length, each field of the String Array would be converted into an int, so it can be sorted.

The problem is that I don't know how to add an undefined number of chars to a `String`.
What I do is the following:

```
public class StartHere {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers;
    String input;
    boolean fieldUsed = false;
    int len = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scanner.next();
    numbers = new int[input.length()];
    String[] aux = new String[input.length()];
    int numOfAuxField = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        do{
        if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))){
            aux[numOfAuxField].append((input.charAt(i)).toString());
            i++;
            fieldUsed = true;
        }else{
            if(fieldUsed == true){
                numOfAuxField++;
            }
        } while(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)));
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < numbers.length; a++){
        if(aux[a] != null){
        numbers[a] = Integer.parseInt(aux[a]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But it says

> Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type char

in the 16th line.
I already looked for an answer but they are all for a predefined number of characters.

What could I do?

Comment: Instead of `.toString`, cast to a string by putting `(String)` before the character.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what a user would input and the result you are expecting? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to put the numbers in a string anyway? Why not just a `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: since you are reading the input char by char, did you handled the numbers which have more than 1 digit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use one of the following ways:

1. `Character.toString(input.charAt(i))`
2. `"" + input.charAt(i)`
3. `String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))`

instead of `(input.charAt(i)).toString()`

---

Primitive types have no methods to work with them.

Comment: Or simply `"" + input.charAt(i)` or `String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))`

Answer (score 4):

you can just change

```
(input.charAt(i)).toString()
```

To

```
String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class does already do tokens: it can recognize numbers.

You could also use a BufferedReader.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String line = in.readLine();
if (line == null) { //  Nothing read
    return;
}
```

Then one can split the line of input into numbers, separated by the pattern `\D+` = sequence of non-digits.

```
String[] numbers = line.split("\\D+");

int[] integers = new int[numbers.lengh()];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
    integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
}

Arrays.sort(integers);
```

Your approach is fine too, but then one does not know in advance how many numbers were entered. Hence, as arrays are fixed-size, better use a `List<String>`, or maybe immediately convert to integers. The API works like this:

```
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add("123");
int n = numbers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    String number = list.get(i);
}
for (String number : numbers) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing `aux[numOfAuxField].append((input.charAt(i)).toString());`
by
`aux[numOfAuxField] += (String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)));`

Joop Eggen: I don't know too much about the Scanner class, so your answer will serve me as a list of things that I have to look for on Google.

Thank you all for the help.